# Check if required variable has been passed

Tags: python

I have a function which requires a parameter (`whateverName(n)`) to be passed in. I want to check if the parameter was indeed passed and if it wasn't, I want to display a prompt asking what the desired parameter should be (`n = int(raw_input(...))`). Any ideas how this can be done (note: I'm a rookie in Python)?

Comment: If you need the parameter to be there, just don't give it a default value.

Comment: If your function requires a parameter and it isn't supplied, your program will crash with `TypeError: <function_name> takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`, or in 3.X `TypeError: <function_name> missing 1 required positional argument: '<variable_name>'`. They seem descriptive enough already - no need to do anything special to change that.

Comment: I know it'll crash, I want to prevent it by displaying the prompt asking what the variable is.

Comment: That's straightforward `try/except` logic @Cube.

Comment: alternatively, validate `n` has been assigned *before* you invoke the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `n` a default value of None, and check for it in the function body.

```
>>> def frob(n=None):
...     if n is None:
...             n = int(raw_input("Please enter a value:"))
...     return n**2 + n
...
>>> frob(23)
552
>>> frob()
Please enter a value:42
1806
```

Of course, this means that the user will be unable to call `frob(None)` even if he's sure that's the value he wants `n` to have. But in this particular case, `frob` can only successfully handle integers anyway, so the user shouldn't need to call `frob(None)` anyway.

Comment: You can use a custom sentinel that the user couldn't possibly need to provide as input: `sentinel=object(); def from(n=sentinel): if n is sentinel: ...`

Comment: @chepner, yeah, that's definitely a valid approach. If the user is in the right scope, he could still do `frob(sentinel)`, but then he's really just asking for trouble.

Comment: Might also want a try/except.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def whatever(n=None):
    if n is None:
        n = input("Enter n:")
    print(n)
```